# flutter plugin: show IOS native dialog with custom view

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, flutter-plugin

I have this view :

[image]

and this is its code :

```
class CustomDialog: UIView {

    var vc: UIViewController!
    
    var view: UIView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
    ....
    

    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
     init(frame: CGRect, inView: UIViewController) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
         
         vc = inView
        
    }
    
    func xibSetup(frame: CGRect){
        self.view = loadNibView()
        view.frame = frame
        
        addSubview(view)
    }
    
    
    
    func loadNibView() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomDialog", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
        return view
    
    }
}
```

I am loading my view like this:

```
public class FlutterTheoryPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin
{
    
    var customDialog: CustomDialog!
    

    public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
        
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: Constants.METHOD_CHANNEL_NAME, binaryMessenger: registrar. Messenger())
        let instance = FlutterTheoryPlugin()
        registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
    }
    
    public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
        switch call.method {
        case Constants.INITIATE_EVENTS:
                  
            let viewController: UIViewController =
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController)!;

            let basisAlert = TheoryAlert()
                basisAlert.showBaseAlert(viewController: viewController)
                        result(true)
        default:
            result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
        }
        
    }
    
    }
    
    class TheoryAlert {
        
        var customDialog: CustomDialog!        
        
        private let backgroundView: UIView = {
            let backgroundView = UIView()
            backgroundView.backgroundColor = .black
            backgroundView.alpha = 0
            return backgroundView
            
        }()
        
        private let alertView: UIView = {
            let alert = UIView()
            alert.backgroundColor = .white
            alert.layer.masksToBounds = true
            alert.layer.cornerRadius = 12
            return alert
        }()
        
        
        
        
        func showBaseAlert(viewController: UIViewController) {
            
            guard let targetView = viewController.view else {
                return
            }
            
            backgroundView.frame = targetView.bounds
            targetView.addSubview(backgroundView)
            targetView.addSubview(alertView)
            
            
            alertView.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: -300, width: targetView.frame.size.width, height: 300)
            
            self.customDialog = CustomDialog(frame: targetView.frame, inView: viewController)
            
            alertView.addSubview(customDialog)
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.backgroundView.alpha =  0.6
            }, completion: {
                done in
                
                if done {
                    
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                        self.alertView.center = targetView.center
                    })
                    
                    
                    
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

When I am using my IOS plugin on my flutter app , all view want s to be shown, but I need just the view, this is the result on the Flutter:

[image]